# Changing inconsistent excel column names into a single name upon reading into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-cleaning

I have an excel document with hundreds of sheets that has the same data, except the sheet columns are not uniformly labeled, one column I need in particular has three different column names that vary by sheet.

**Example Excel Workbook:**

```
date         cats       garbage column      
12-03-1978   Heathcliff    trees
12-15-1966   Garfield      grass
 
sheet 1
```

```
felines     date        garbage column
Simba      09-20-1989    ROSW
Mufasa     07-01-1986    TFA

sheet 2
```

```
garbage column  date       gatos
rocks         04-04-2021   Oliver
lava          03-05-2014   Felix

sheet 3
```

*there would be many sheets after this.*

**Important Things to Note**

- **"cats","felines","gatos"** represent the set of strings of columns of interest in the excel doc I want consolidates all under a single column in a dataframe called "cats", and that set of strings does not change and is consistent.
- Along with that column, there are other columns of interest, such as "date" (as an example) which are consistently labeled through the sheets, along with other columns which I just ignore and do not want pulled in ie "garbage column(s)".
- The column order is not consistent across sheets.
- The number of sheets in this workbook is extremely large and is occasionally added to. ie mapping/assigning a sheet name to a particular string won't work and is not practical, however **the set** of strings ("cats","felines","gatos") **does not change.** It will always be one of those three which I wanted consolidated regardless of column position or if it is a new sheet is added without having to update the code.

**Desired Output of DataFrame after Reading in Excel:**

```
cats         date
Heathcliff   12-03-1978
Garfield     12-15-1966
Simba        09-20-1989
Mufasa       07-01-1986
Oliver       04-04-2021
Felix        03-05-2014
```

**What I attempted and Where I'm stuck:**

If it weren't for the inconsistent nature of the the cat/feline/gatos column, I would have something like this:

```
cols = ["date", 
        "cat",
        "column_of_interest",
        "column_of_interest2," #there would be more, etc etc
       ]

workbook = pd.ExcelFile("Cat_Catalog.xlsx")
sheets = workbook.sheet_names

df = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(workbook, usecols=cols, sheet_name=s)
                .assign(sheet_name=s) for s in sheets])
```

Typically I'd attempt a mapping and use the map. eg

```
column_mapping = {"cats":"cats","felines":"cats","gatos":"cats"}

cols = ["date", 
        map(column_mapping,"cat_column"),
        "column_of_interest", 
        "column_of_interest2," 
       ]
```

But that is obviously not going to work because the `iter` argument in `map` is neither consistent in name nor position.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You should rename the columns using your dictionary in every sheet before concating:

```
column_mapping = {"cats":"cats","felines":"cats","gatos":"cats"}
workbook = pd.ExcelFile("Cat_Catalog.xlsx")
sheets = workbook.sheet_names
df_agg = pd.DataFrame()
for s in sheets:
    df = pd.read_excel(workbook, usecols=cols, sheet_name=s).assign(sheet_name=s)
    df.columns = df.columns.to_series().map(column_mapping)
    df = pd.concat([df_agg, df])
```

Comment: Is there a bit of code missing? I'm getting a syntax or indent error with the hanging `.assign(sheet_name=s)`

Comment: @JLuu - try it now

Comment: I'm getting an error message `ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['cats']`

Comment: what was the `cols` list you used for the `usecols` parameter?

Comment: I added it as you added it in your original code. I am not sure you need it at all